# Rascal error installing artifact missing

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rascal

Hello everyone i'm getting a error installing Rascal plugin. I tried installing it from http://update.rascal-mpl.org/stable/ but i get the following error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.rcp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Artifact not found: http://update.rascal-mpl.org/stable/plugins/org.eclipse.imp.pdb.values_0.4.2.201506052148.jar.
>   http://update.rascal-mpl.org/stable/plugins/org.eclipse.imp.pdb.values_0.4.2.201506052148.jar

I tried installing it on different eclipse versions (juno, luna(4.4) and luna RCP) on different OS (ubuntu and windows) and different locations.

All give the same error. I just looked at the index of http://update.rascal-mpl.org/stable/plugins/ and cant find org.eclipse.imp.pdb.values_0.4.2.201506052148.jar there.

I hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were in the process of updating the stable plugin, something went wrong there.

It should work now, you might have to refresh the update site. (or start with a new eclipse).